# Getting images from a page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm attempting to grab only the images from a page in Wordpress.

I read there was a function called `get_post_gallery()` but it doesn't seem to obtain my images. This is what I did:

```
if ( get_post_gallery() ) :
   $images = get_post_gallery(get_the_ID(), false);

   foreach($images as $image)
   {
      echo $image['src'];
   }
endif;
```

This line of code is put inside `the loop` from what I understand like so:

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
   \\Bit of code in here
}
```

However, the array that it returns appears to be empty (even though there are images in the post page editor). **Do you guys suggest this way or another way to retrieve only images from a post/page?**

Comment: Are your images in a gallery or are they embedded in the post content?

Comment: Ah, I see what's going on here. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: :) That what I thought. If they aren't in a gallery, you need to search for type 'image' and parent 'post_ID'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found your answer in another [SO question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61393/get-images-attached-to-post).

Here it is:

```
function wpse_get_images() {
    global $post;
    $id = intval( $post->ID );
    $size = 'medium';
    $attachments = get_children( array(
            'post_parent' => $id,
            'post_status' => 'inherit',
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'post_mime_type' => 'image',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'orderby' => 'menu_order'
        ) );
    if ( empty( $attachments ) )
                return '';

    $output = "\n";
/**
 * Loop through each attachment
 */
foreach ( $attachments as $id  => $attachment ) :

    $title = esc_html( $attachment->post_title, 1 );
    $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id, $size );

    $output .= '<a class="selector thumb" href="' . esc_url( wp_get_attachment_url( $id ) ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $title ) . '">';
    $output .= '<img class="aligncenter" src="' . esc_url( $img[0] ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( $title ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $title ) . '" />';
    $output .= '</a>';

endforeach;

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming this is put in the `functions.php` file?

Comment: Yes, and you call the function wherever you need it.